# Problems with Windows Forms using string data type C++

Tags: c++, string, winforms

I'm currently using Windows Form Application in C++ and I have a little problem.
So, I have a class called Product with the following attributes:

```
#pragma once

include <string>

using std::string

class CProduct
{
  protected:
    string name;
    string code;

  public:
    CProduct();
    ~CProduct();
    CProduct(string code, string name);
    string getCode();
    string getName();
};
```

And then, I insert two textBox, textBox1 for the name and the textBox2 for the code.

```
/* Code above*/
#pragma endregion
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
    if (textBox1->Text->Length == 0 || textBox2->Text->Length == 0)
        MessageBox::Show("Try again");
    else
    {
        string  name = textBox1->Text;/* Error is here */
        string  code = textBox2->Text;/* Error is here */
        CProducto*Nuevo = new CProducto(name, code); 
    }
}
};
}
```

But, an error appears:

error C2440 : 'initializing' : cannot convert from System::String ^  to std::basic_string ,std::allocator>

Is there any way to solve this problem? Am I doing something wrong or missing something?
Please, let me know. Thanks

Comment: You need to post at least the code where the error is happening.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1b4az623.aspx

Comment: I already post the code where the error is happening. Please, check it.

Comment: And paddy has already posted a link to the answer. TL;DR: `string` and `String` are not the same.

Comment: But, how can I solve this problem? I dont' wanna use char*name and char*code. String is better.